# Creating one big array from two different arrays by comparing values PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a MySQL table with reports. Fetching my reports is used by function:

```
function fillItByRoute($lat){
global $db;
$array = array(array());
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE latitude LIKE '$lat%' ORDER BY datetime_view");
    while ($row = $db->fetch_array($result)){
        $array[$int][1] = "Desc";
        $array[$int][2] = $row['latitude'];
    }
return $array;
```

}

which creates an multidimensional array.

- *[latitudes in MySQL are stored like 25.33236645, 23.2665666 etc...]*

I have a different array:

```
$array_lat = array(25.5,23.1,45.2);
```

So, I would like to know if it is possible to get through array values of $array_lat with checking the match with values from multidimensional array created by function fillItByRoute() and storing values of function fillItByRoute() in new array?

One more time, shortly:

1. There are different values in $array_lat;
2. I want to check function fillItByRoute() with input of $array_lat
3. Results, which suit have to be stored in new array.
4. The new array should be with values (using values of my $array_lat): 25.5666332, 25.511433, 23.1233, 23.11444, 23.1, 45.269...etc, could be even hundreds of items.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is $int,$lat and what do you want to check

Comment: So if you have in $array_lat the value 25.5 , and you receive from mysql a 25.5666332 value then you want the value returned by mysql to be in your new array.. is that what you mean?

Comment: @Nelson Yes, all values included in 25.5, (IE, your: 25.5666332) should be passed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this. It iterates through your array_lat and compares it to a value from SQL. I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the comparison but you should put it in the if statement from the second function. If you want a new array it looks like you understand how to create those but let me know if this is too ambiguous.

```
function fillItByRoute($lat){
global $db;
$array = array(array());
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE latitude LIKE '$lat%' ORDER BY datetime_view");
    while ($row = $db->fetch_array($result)){
        $array[$int][1] = "Desc";
        $array[$int][2] = $row['latitude'];
    }
return $array;

function compareArrToSql($array_lat){
    for($curr_lat = 0; $curr_lat<count($array_lat); $curr_lat++){
        $sql_val = fillItByRoute($array_lat[$curr_lat]);
        if($array_lat[$curr_lat]==$sql_val){
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption about what you  meant is correct, this is what you are after:

```
function fillItByRoute($lat){
   global $db;
   $array = array(array());
   $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE latitude LIKE '$lat%' ORDER BY datetime_view");
    while ($row = $db->fetch_array($result)){
        $latitude = number_format((float)$row['latitude'], 2, '.', '');
        if (in_array($latitude,$lat)) {
           $array[$int][1] = "Desc";
           $array[$int][2] = $row['latitude'];
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: But I want to compare (using MySQL LIKE) values from $array_lat. In your piece of code don't see $array_lat variable at all.

Comment: how many items do $array_lat typically has? because they will need to be inserted in the sql for do what you want, and if the array is too large the sql will have a length limit..

Comment: About 10 - 50 (100 maximally)

Comment: Sorry, after giving another look can't understand what you want.